# Algorithm - How to find the minimum total reading time of n-texts when we have each text's length and frequency?

Tags: algorithm

The problem sounds like this, we are given n-texts and they are going to be placed on a tape/ribbon/band(don't really know what's the equivalent in english,
but I think you understand what I'm talking about). In order to read the text situated at a position k, we have to read the texts from positions 1,2,...,k.
Each text has its' own length and frequency(number of times it is read). Now, we have to come up with a solution of placing the texts in such an order that
the total accesing time to be minimum.
The formula for calculating the total accesing time is:

```
n_
 \  f(Ti)[L(T1)+L(T2)+...+L(Ti)]
 /_    
i=1
```

> Now, that little drawing I did is SUM from 1 to n;
>
> f(T i) is the  frequency of T i;
>
> L(T i) is the length of T i;
>
> T i is the text situated at position i;

Here is an equivalent in "pseudocode" in case it helps:

```
n-number of texts;
Ribbon[n]-array of texts
sum=0, sum2=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {sum=0;
   for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
      sum=sum+Ribbon[j].length;
   sum2=sum2+sum*Ribbon[i].frequency;}
```

Now I tried a couple of tactics, such as sorting the texts in ascending/descending order, according to the length, to the frequency, or even to the length*frequency and also some other couple ideas I had, and none of them worked out, as I always found a counter-example, an element-order that had a smaller total accesing time than what my program gave me.

Comment: Is there an upper bound for the number of texts (`n`)?

Comment: @גלעדברקן No, there is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the change in the total sum if we swap two adjacent elements x and y (where x is currently placed immediately before y).

You will find that the difference is `f(Tx)L(Ty)-f(Ty)L(Tx)`.

For example, if the two lengths are the same, then we reduce the sum if we put the higher frequency earlier, while if the frequency is the same, we reduce the sum if we put the shorter length earlier.

We can reach any permutation by swapping adjacent elements (e.g. consider bubble sort), and so if you order the elements according to this comparison function you will achieve the minimum sum.

Note that this comparison function is equivalent to ordering based on `L(Tx)/f(Tx)`, i.e. we want the short/high frequency elements to be done first.

Comment: I did as you said, ordering them based on L(Tx)/f(Tx) and it worked. But I got another question where I'd like your help if you got the time, I posted an answer below where I wrote the question.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, I ordered them based on the L(Tx)/f(Tx), just as Peter de Rivaz said, and it worked.

---

EDIT:

However, there's a twist for this problem, a second-part if you wish. It goes like this: we still get n-texts, but this time, the texts only have lengths, no frequency. And they are going to be put on a certain number of bands(p), so there will be p-bands(ribbons/tapes).

Reading a text from a band still goes the same way, in order to read the text situated at position k on a band, we have to read the texts from positions 1,2,...,k on that band.

Now, we have to figure out a way of placing the texts on the p-bands so that we get a global accesing time that is minimum. This time, the global accesing time is calculated by adding all the total accesing times from each band.

Also, the total accesing time is calculated this way now:

```
n_
 \  [L(T1)+L(T2)+...+L(Ti)]
 /_    
i=1
```

We leave out the frequency part, as it is no longer part of the problem.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as the first question if you set f(i) equal to 1 for all elements?

Comment: @Peter de Rivaz Well, not quite. Because this time we actually have p number of bands, instead of just one.

Comment: Ah, I see the difference now - I was looking at the formula (which looks very similar to before), and hadn't read the English carefully enough.  This should probably be a new question rather than an answer.

Comment: By the way, for this problem I would probably use a dynamic programming solution working out the cost of placing the x shortest texts into y bands.  This should work, but will have complexity around O(n^3) so may be too slow for your purposes.